# Union of conjugates of a connected subgroup of a matrix group is connected.

Tags: matrices, lie-groups, connectedness

Let $H$ be any connected subgroup of a matrix group $G$. Show that $S = \bigcup_{x \in G} xHx^{-1}$ is connected.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: if a family of connected sets has a common element, the union of these connected sets must be connected.